# Angularjs filter matches all properties in an object even though only one property is in my table

Tags: angularjs

I have a fitler on a table. The data in the table is only a subset of all the data I need. I would like to filter just on the information that is included in my table columns instead of all the data.

The data is a history object that has an event user. The user is the person who made the change. So in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VfJXU/) Jordy made changes to himself, but now I can't filter by the name that he changed because it is his current name and so the filter matches the event user's name. The default filter works great for data that is not included in the user. So my question is whether or not a default filter could have exclusions/inclusions or if I am stuck writing a new filter.

I have seen where you can filter specifically on object properties of the user object itself, but I couldn't figure out how to do that and still filter on the event data.

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.searchText = "Jordy"

$scope.events = [{
    "id": 8,
        "version": 0,
        "eventUser": {
            "email": "def@a.com",
            "nameFirst": "Jordy",
            "nameLast": "Nelson"
    },
        "eventField": "nameLast",
        "valueOld": "Nelsons",
        "valueNew": "Nelson",
        "eventDate": "Jan 7, 2014 04:05 PM"
}, {
    "id": 7,
        "version": 0,
        "eventUser": {
        "email": "def@a.com",
            "nameFirst": "Jordy",
            "nameLast": "Nelson"
    },
        "eventField": "nameFirst",
        "valueOld": "Jordys",
        "valueNew": "Jordy",
        "eventDate": "Jan 7, 2014 04:05 PM"
}, {
    "id": 6,
        "version": 0,
        "eventUser": {
        "email": "def@a.com",
            "nameFirst": "Jordy",
            "nameLast": "Nelson"
    },
        "eventField": "timeZoneId",
        "valueOld": "Pacific/Tahiti",
        "valueNew": "Pacific/Niue",
        "eventDate": "Jan 7, 2014 01:43 PM"
}, {
    "id": 5,
        "version": 0,
        "eventUser": {
        "email": "def@a.com",
            "nameFirst": "Jordy",
            "nameLast": "Nelson"
    },
        "eventField": "timeZoneId",
        "valueOld": "America/Boise",
        "valueNew": "Pacific/Tahiti",
        "eventDate": "Jan 7, 2014 10:26 AM"
}, {
    "id": 4,
        "version": 0,
        "eventUser": {
        "email": "def@a.com",
            "nameFirst": "Jordy",
            "nameLast": "Nelson"
    },
        "eventField": "title",
        "valueOld": "",
        "valueNew": "s",
        "eventDate": "Jan 7, 2014 10:25 AM"
}, {
    "id": 3,
        "version": 0,
        "eventUser": {
        "email": "def@a.com",
            "nameFirst": "Jordy",
            "nameLast": "Nelson"
    },
        "eventField": "nameLast",
        "valueOld": "Nelson",
        "valueNew": "Nelsons",
        "eventDate": "Jan 7, 2014 10:25 AM"
}, {
    "id": 2,
        "version": 0,
        "eventUser": {
        "email": "b@a.com",
            "nameFirst": "Jordy",
            "nameLast": "Nelson"
    },
        "eventField": "nameFirst",
        "valueOld": "Jordy",
        "valueNew": "Jordys",
        "eventDate": "Jan 7, 2014 10:25 AM"
}, {
    "id": 1,
        "version": 0,
        "eventUser": {
        "email": "a@a.com",
            "nameFirst": "Jordy",
            "nameLast": "Nelson"
    },
        "eventField": "password",
        "valueOld": "Old Password",
        "valueNew": "New Password",
        "eventDate": "Jan 6, 2014 05:03 PM"
}]
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="event in events|filter:searchText">
        <td>{{event.id}}</td>
        <td>{{event.valueOld}}</td>
        <td>{{event.valueNew}}</td>
        <td>{{event.eventUser.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VfJXU/

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events|filter:{thePropertyYouWant:searchText}">
```

replace *thePropertyYouWant* with the property name you want to search by.

Comment: This works if the filter was only applying to the column that was property specific, but then all the other columns would stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter a particular property (or properties) of an object by binding your search text field to a property of an object with the same property name as the objects you are trying to filter.  This allows you to use multiple fields/properties in your filters.

For instance:

Replace

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
<table>
```

With

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="searchText.id"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="searchText.valueOld"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="searchText.valueNew"></td>
  </tr>
```

simplified example of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dspies/e3Kz4/2/

** Edit: You also need to remove or change the following to an object

```
$scope.searchText = "Jordy"
```

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to keep the single input for all the columns. We might end up changing the design this way though. Thank you for responding. Also setting the searchText default was just so people using the fiddle could see what name should go there.